# scala how to use val instead of var

Tags: scala, increment, var

I am very new to Scala and I wrote some code using `var`. I heard using `var` is not recommended in Scala so I want to try using `val` only. I researched and tried different ways but could not produce the same result as I used `var`.

```
def yearly_yield(data: List[List[Option[Double]]], balance: Long, index: Int): Long = {
  val year = data(index)
  var size = 0
  var invYield = 0.0

  for( j <- year)
    if(j.isDefined)
      size = size + 1

  val amount = balance/size

  for( i <- year.indices)
    if (year(i).isDefined)
      invYield += amount * year(i).get

  balance + invYield.toLong
}
```

and the other one is

```
def compound_yield(data: List[List[Option[Double]]], balance: Long, index: Int): Long = {
  var newBalance = balance
  for( i <- 0 until index) 
    newBalance = yearly_yield(data, newBalance, i)

  newBalance
}
```

I think I can try using recursion for `compound_yield` but I am consistently getting errors..

Comment: Does your example compile? ```yield``` is a keyword in scala.

Comment: ah that's true, thanks for spotting that! I don't know how that happened

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things you can improve on here. First of all, your function should just return the yield for one year. If you have a list of years, you can iterate over that and call it on each on. Second, you will improve your Scala code substantially just by familiarizing yourself with the various operations you can perform on collections. In this case, what you're really doing is just a fold operaiton. In general, those are much preferable to loops in Scala. In fact, once you get used to them loops start looking much uglier in comparison! Additionally, because of associativity, you can just multiply by balance/size at the end instead of every time.

```
def yearly_yield(data: List[Option[Double]], balance: Long): Long =
{
  val year = data.flatten //Remove all the None's
  (year.fold(0.0)(_+_)*balance/year.size).toLong
}
```

Your compound yield operation is then just folding the annual yield from left to right.

```
def compound_yield(data: List[List[Option[Double]]], balance): Long = 
  data.foldLeft(0l)((balance, year) => balance * yearly_yield(year))
```

Comment: ugh ... Recomputing `year.size` on every iteration is ... ugh!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
def yearly_yield(data    :List[List[Option[Double]]]
                ,balance :Long, index: Int) :Long = {
  val year   :List[Double] = data(index).flatten
  val amount :Long         = balance/year.length

  year.foldLeft(0.0){case (acc, d) => acc + amount * d}.toLong

}

def compound_yield(data    :List[List[Option[Double]]]
                  ,balance :Long, index: Int) :Long =
  (0 until index).foldLeft(balance){ case (nb, idx) =>
    yearly_yield(data, nb, idx)
  }
```

Comment: I am sorry i made a mistake when declaring one of the vars. Yield is a reserved word and somehow it's written like that in here

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  Doesn't change my suggested code.

Comment: `acc` should be on the left

Answer (score 0):

So, yearly is simple:

```
def yearly(data: List[Option[Double]], balance: Long): Double = {
  val interest = year.flatten
  interest.map(_ * balance).sum / interest.size
}
```

You don't need to send all the years, and the index in just to look at one (and random access for `List` is not something you should do either way), so I adjusted the parameters accordingly. It should also be returning `Double` rather than `Long`.

`.flatten` here turns `List[Option[Double]]` into `List[Double]` by throwing out those options that are `None`, and unwrapping the others into `Double`. 
`.map` traverses the list, and calls the function for each element (`_` is shorthand for the argument, which is the current list element). 
Then we add everything together `.sum`, and divide by the size (this last part seems wrong, I don't know why you want to do that BTW).

Note, that `.flatten`, `.map`, `.sum` and `.size` each traverses the same list, which may be considered wasteful. If `year` is a list of months, and there are like 12 of them, it doesn't really matter, and I would urge you to do it this way for the sake of expressiveness. But if we are talking about billions of elements, possibly fetched from remote storage, it may become prohibitive. For that case, there is always `.foldLeft`:

```
 val (total, size) = data.foldLeft((0, 0)) { 
   case ((total, size), Some(elem)) => (total + elem*balance, size + 1)
   case (passThrough, _) => passThrough
 }
 total/size
```

This does the same as the first version, but with just a single pass through the list.
`.foldLeft` traverses the list like `.map` does, but instead of just passing the current list element to your function, it passes what it returned the last time (or the initial value, you give it as a parameter for the first call), and the current element, and in the end what you get back is the result of the last function execution, not the entire list.

Now, to compounding. You want to start with a balance, and go through each year, applying the transformation. `.foldLeft` does just that:

```
 data.foldLeft(balance) { case (balance, year) => balance + yearly(year, balance) }
```